# biquad filter output getting amplified in C implementation

Tags: c, filtering, signal-processing

I was trying to implement a biquad lowpass filter in C, according to the equation

> y[n] = a0*x[n] + a1*x[n-1] + a2*x[n-2] – b1*y[n-1] – b2*y[n-2]

I gave a sine sweep input with amplitude 0.8, and output is filtered. but the amplitude of sine is increasing and getting clipped. is this because of any mistake in the C code?

code is

```
    #include <stdio.h>
//#include 

float in_state[40];
float out_state[40];
#define blocksize  32

float coeff[5] = {
    0.6589417254311722,
    1.3178834508623445,
    0.6589417254311722,
    -1.1314481923390387,
    -0.5043187093856503,
};
void biquad(float* x, float * y)
{
    in_state[0] = in_state[blocksize];
    in_state[1] = in_state[blocksize+1];

    out_state[0] = out_state[blocksize];
    out_state[1] = out_state[blocksize+1];
#if 1
    for(int i=0;i<blocksize;i++)
    {
        in_state[i+2]=x[i];
    }
#endif
    for(int i = 0; i<blocksize;i++)
    {
        float temp = coeff[0]*in_state[i+2]+    // a0 * x[n]
            coeff[1]*in_state[i+1]+             // a1 * x[n-1]
            coeff[2]*in_state[i]+               // a2 * x[n-2]
            coeff[3]*out_state[i+1]+            // -b1 * y[n-1]
            coeff[4]*out_state[i];              // -b2 * y[n-2]

        out_state[i+2] = temp;

        y[i]=temp;
    }
}


int main()
{
    FILE *infile = fopen("sweep.dat","rb");
    FILE *outfile = fopen("filter.dat","wb");

    float inbuf[32],outbuf[32];

    while(fread(inbuf,sizeof(float),blocksize,infile) == blocksize)
    {
        biquad(inbuf,outbuf);

        fwrite(outbuf,sizeof(float),blocksize,outfile);
    }
    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);
}
```

filter coefficients I took from this site [Biquad calculator](http://www.earlevel.com/main/2013/10/13/biquad-calculator-v2/)

Comment: Shouldn't the last part of your equation be `- coeff[3] * out_state[i+1] - coeff[4] * out_state[i]` (the signs need to be fixed)?  I couldn't really verify your coefficients because there's not really enough information to drive the biquad page in your problem statement.

Comment: yes, but to compensate that i reversed the signs of the coefficients coeff[3] and coeff[4]

Comment: That's what I was curious about but since there wasn't enough information, I couldn't verify you actually did that.  Thanks for clarifying though.

Answer (score 1):

You introduced gain to the filter coefficients. Make sure you have uniform gain. You have to select 0 dB gain on the site :)